# Get a list of all files inside of a directory in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, file-listing

How can you obtain a list of files (as a stringcollection or some other storage method) which contains the full path on the user's computer to the files?

Is there a method for doing so?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks like you want to use `Directory.GetFiles()` in the `System.IO` namespace.

[Docs here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles.aspx).

Comment: Question, how can I get all the files inside of all the subdirectories as well?

Comment: There's probably a pre-defined method for it, but otherwise just right a simple recursion.

Comment: Ugh, that's *write* a simple recursion, sorry.

Comment: @Cyclone: please read the documentation that was linked. Hint: Directory.GetFiles(string, string, SearchOptions)

Comment: Directory.GetFiles(Path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories) did it. Much easier than what I was trying to do with it lol...

Answer (score 6):

```
    Dim txtFiles = Directory.GetFiles("C:\Input", "*.CSV", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).
        [Select](Function(nm) Path.GetFileName(nm))

    Dim arrayList As New System.Collections.ArrayList()
    For Each filenm As String In txtFiles
        arrayList.Add(New clsImportFiles(filenm))
    Next
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a Listbox to Windows Form and Add following code on Form Load  or other events :-

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles("Your Directory PAth Here"))
```

Hope IT Helps ; From  Nirav