# How to create a list file in VB?

Tags: vb.net, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get a list of all files inside of a directory in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457525/get-a-list-of-all-files-inside-of-a-directory-in-vb-net)

I need to search many file in a network drive. It is very slow to use the search function one by one in Window explorer under XP. My plan is to create a VB program to generate a whole list of available files in string format first, then use string search function in the list. My question is how to create a directory list using VB?

Thanks

Comment: See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx#Y0 for `Directory.GetFiles()` method. Or see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1457525/210709

Comment: Would you please put your comment to the answer section. I will mark that you give the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [MSDN: `Directory.GetFiles()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx#Y0) method.

Answer (score 1):

Someone had answered a somewhat similar question I found here, [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428136/get-all-folder-directories-list-in-vb-net)
I might suggest trying using a contains method to check if an item contains a string and then adding this to a second list to contain possible matches. Something like

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Public Function GetFileMatches(byval searchText as string) as list(of string)

Dim fileMatches as new list(of string)

for each directory in GetDirectories("c:\", "*")
       for each file in GetFiles(directory,"*")
          if file.contains(searchText) then fileMatches.add(file)
       next

next

return fileMatches
End Function
```

Might be able to apply some threading to speed it up as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can use FileSystemObject for this.

you can refer the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zfk1t850%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to use VB, just do

```
dir *.* /s > filelist.txt
```

And it will output the directory listing to file filelist.txt and you can open it in notepad.