# how to list all files names under a folder in hard drive?

Tags: vb.net, file, directory, hard-drive

I want to list all files names exist under folder in hard drive with vb.net , and i don't know how.First ,i choose a folder with folderbrowser component, next,i list all files

Here is my code (only for choose a folder)

```
   dossier_disque.ShowDialog()
    txt_folder.Text = dossier_disque.SelectedPath
```

for list all files , i tried to use for each , but it's not correct

my code when i tried to list file

```
        Dim files() As String = Directory.GetFiles(txt_folder.Text)
    For Each a In CStr(files.Count)
        folder_hard.Rows.Add(Directory.GetFiles(txt_folder.Text))
    Next
```

folder_hard is a grid name 
txt_folder is a name of a folder path

With this code , the result , i can see only the first file twice in grid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a list of all files inside of a directory in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457525/get-a-list-of-all-files-inside-of-a-directory-in-vb-net)

Comment: same result , i edit my post

Comment: Is this a homework and you don't know how to do it? ;-) You know, you are looping through a number and not the file-list? E.g. if you have 587 files in your folder, your For-loop returns you 3 chars. '5', '8', '7'! I think, you wanted to loop through the files-array and add them to your DGV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with your for each loop:
CStr() converts values into strings.
So your for loop is looping through each char in the string of the number of files in the files array.
So change it to:

```
For Each a In files
```

Then a will be each file name in the files array.
If you want to add each to your grid you need to change that line to :

```
folder_hard.Rows.Add(a)
```

So this should work:

```
Dim files() As String = Directory.GetFiles(txt_folder.Text)
For Each a In files
    folder_hard.Rows.Add(a)
Next
```