# How to get all files in Temp directory vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have an problem and I need help , I want to get all files in Temp directory . Im using this code but it doesn't work at all :| It doesn't get files from folders. I appreciate any help :)

```
    For Each File In Directory.GetFiles("C:\Windows\Temp")
        MsgBox(File)
    Next
```

Comment: That is fairly unlikely to be desirable, consider [Path.GetTempPath()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Does the application have enough permissions to read the content of that folder?

Comment: Yes Im running it as admin

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't get files from sub folders? Are you sure there are any files in that exact directory?

Comment: Yes ,It doesn't get files from subfolders and folders.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to list all files names under a folder in hard drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46091557/how-to-list-all-files-names-under-a-folder-in-hard-drive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to include searching in subfolders. See MSDN for all info on [GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx) and [SearchOption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
For Each File In Directory.GetFiles("C:\Windows\Temp", *, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    MsgBox(File)
Next
```