# Read out file names

Tags: vb.net

I want to read out file names but the file names are not in the listbox, for example I have a file with 3 text files in there and I want to see the text files name in the listbox. At the web i found this code but it read not the file names

```
For Each Filename In FileIO.FileSystem.GetFileInfo("C:\Windows\Fonts\").Name
        listbox1.Items.Add(Filename)
    Next
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a list of all files inside of a directory in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457525/get-a-list-of-all-files-inside-of-a-directory-in-vb-net)

Comment: Your code just returns the name of the last folder in the path `C:\Windows\Fonts` and adds each character of it to the listbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
Dim FolderInfo = New DirectoryInfo("C:\Windows\Fonts\")
For Each File In FolderInfo.GetFiles
    ListBox1.Items.Add(File)
Next
```

Comment: @Bastitron Please accept the answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.

Comment: @Bastitron If it has solved your problem, you can accept answer by clicking the  check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.

Comment: @Bharath Sorry =)